# Does people saying "Don't vote" online work?

Tags: united-states, voter-turnout

There were lots of instances leading up to the 2016 election of robots posting messages targeting both liberals and moderates. For progressives they said things like "Don't vote, Bernie fans. Hillary Clinton is a corrupt establishment figure." For black voters, they could use a different message like, "Obama isn't on the ballot. Your life won't be better if she's president, so why not just sit this one out?"

There were also instances that I saw targeting the Georgia runoff elections saying things like "The election was STOLEN! Don't vote in the runoff, if the Democrats win it's because it's RIGGED. Don't waste your time!" It is not clear what the political affiliation of people posting "don't vote in the runoff" was, because it was apparently both people on the left and right pushing that message. But the one about Russia has been shown to have been a pro-Trump message.

*Does saying online not to vote by targeting political weaknesses decrease voter turnout by making people feel their vote is useless?*

Comment: I think this is the so-called "smear campaign" or "negative campaigning" that with limited effectiveness among all voters. Also, it is not one-sided but depends on the character of the campaigner. I suggest modifying your question to a less biased standing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a general answer. It depends upon how credible the pitch is. Online disseminated election boycotts that have had success have occurred abroad in the past, and somebody probably heeds any message out of hundred of millions of voters.

But, I'm not aware of scholarly research addressing the question, or even credible quantitative estimates. It is hard to determine as there are so many factors influence voter turnout in both directions and singling out any one of them is challenging.